# Positioning dot before text in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I only know of `\dot`, `\cdot`. How do I get the dot to appear in the top left position of the alphabet?[image]

The following helps, to have a dot after the t.

```
$t^.$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
if $s\in t^\bullet\setminus{}^\bullet t$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: exactly.. it was a bullet, not a dot !

Comment: @GermanShepherd It is a bullet _and_ a _bold_ dot :)) You are welcome.